# Query to get the customers who haven't transacted in the past two months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data in the following format (table name - `ORDERS`):

```
╔══════════╦═════════╦═════════════════════════════╗
║ OrderID  ║ CustNum ║ OrderDate                   ║
╟──────────╫─────────╢─────────────────────────────╢
║ 1        ║ 100     ║ 2015-02-05 00:00:00.0000000 ║
║ 2        ║ 101     ║ 2015-03-05 00:00:00.0000000 ║
║ 4        ║ 102     ║ 2015-04-05 00:00:00.0000000 ║
║ 5        ║ 102     ║ 2015-05-05 00:00:00.0000000 ║
║ 6        ║ 102     ║ 2015-06-05 00:00:00.0000000 ║
║ 10       ║ 101     ║ 2015-06-05 00:00:00.0000000 ║
║ 34       ║ 100     ║ 2015-06-05 00:00:00.0000000 ║
╚══════════╩═════════╩═════════════════════════════╝
```

and I have a `customers` table having customer information in the following format:

```
╔═════════╦══════════╗
║ CustNum ║ CustName ║
╟─────────╫──────────╢
║ 100     ║ ABC      ║
║ 101     ║ DEF      ║
║ 102     ║ GHI      ║
╚═════════╩══════════╝
```

This data spans many years, the `ORDERS` table itself has 5 Million+ records. I would like to know the number of customers who haven't transacted (or placed an order) in the past two months.

In the above example, `CustNum` `100` and `101` haven't transacted for the past two months (if we look at June 2015) and `102` had transacted in the past two months (again, if we look at June 2015), so I would like the output to be in the following format:

```
Time        NumberOfCustNotPlacingOrders
Apr-2014    1 (CustNum 102, didnt place orders in Feb and Mar)
May-2014    1 (CustNum 100, didnt place orders in Mar and Apr)
Jun-2014    2 (CustNum 100 and 101, didnt place orders in Apr and Mar)
```

In other words, I would like to look at an entire month, let's say June 2015 in this case. I would now look to peek 2 months back (April and May) and count how many customers (`CustNum`) didn't place orders, `100` and `101` in this case. **I would like to do this for all the months, say starting Jan 2012 till Jun 2015.**

I would post the initial query that I would have tried, but I really don't have any idea how to achieve this, so it's pretty much a blank slate for me. Seems like a `self join` maybe in order, but I'm not entirely sure.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It is like a blank slate for us too unless you provide some details. Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Is the column OrderDate DateTime?

Comment: A self-join or a WHERE NOT EXISTS() clause would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the first solution, which could be used as a working base.

```
CREATE TABLE #orders(OrderId int identity(1,1), CustNum int, Orderdate date)

-- using system columns to populate demo data (I'm lazy)
INSERT INTO #orders(CustNum,Orderdate)
    SELECT system_type_id, DATEADD(month,column_id*-1,GETDATE())
    FROM sys.all_columns

-- Possible Solution 1:
-- Getting all your customers who haven't placed an order in the last 2 months
SELECT *
FROM (
        -- All your customers
        SELECT DISTINCT CustNum
        FROM #orders
        EXCEPT
        -- All customers who have a transaction in the last 2 months
        SELECT DISTINCT CustNum
        FROM #orders
        WHERE Orderdate >= DATEADD(month,-2,GETDATE())
    ) dat

DROP TABLE #orders
```

Based on the fact that a customer table is available, this can also be a solution:

```
CREATE TABLE #orders(OrderId int identity(1,1), CustNum int, Orderdate date)

-- using system columns to populate demo data (I'm lazy)
INSERT INTO #orders(CustNum,Orderdate)
    SELECT system_type_id, DATEADD(month,column_id*-1,GETDATE())
    FROM sys.all_columns

CREATE TABLE #customers(CustNum int)

-- Populate customer table with demo data
INSERT INTO #customers(CustNum)
    SELECT DISTINCT custNum 
    FROM #orders

-- Possible Solution 2:
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as noTransaction
FROM #customers as c
LEFT JOIN(
        -- All customers who have a transaction in the last 2 months
        SELECT DISTINCT CustNum
        FROM #orders
        WHERE Orderdate >= DATEADD(month,-2,GETDATE())
    ) t
    ON c.CustNum = t.CustNum
WHERE t.CustNum IS NULL

DROP TABLE #orders
DROP TABLE #customers
```

You'll receive a counted value of each customer which hasn't bought anything in the last 2 months. As I've read it, you try to run this query regularly (maybe for a special newsletter or something like that). If you won't count, you'll getting the customer numbers which can be used for further processes.

**Solution with rolling months**
After clearing the question, this should make the thing you're looking for. It generates an output based on rolling months.

```
CREATE TABLE #orders(OrderId int identity(1,1), CustNum int, Orderdate date)

-- using system columns to populate demo data (I'm lazy)
INSERT INTO #orders(CustNum,Orderdate)
    SELECT system_type_id, DATEADD(month,column_id*-1,GETDATE())
    FROM sys.all_columns

CREATE TABLE #customers(CustNum int)

-- Populate customer table with demo data
INSERT INTO #customers(CustNum)
    SELECT DISTINCT custNum 
    FROM #orders

-- Possible Solution with rolling months:
-- first of all, get all available months
-- this can be also achieved with an temporary table (which may be better)
-- but in case, that you can't use an procedure, I'm using the CTE this way.
;WITH months AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART(month,orderdate) as allMonths, 
                    DATEPART(year,orderdate) as allYears
    FROM #orders
)
SELECT m.allMonths,m.allYears, monthyCustomers.noBuyer
FROM months m
OUTER APPLY(
        SELECT N'01/'+m.allMonths+N'/'+m.allYears as monthString, COUNT(c.CustNum) as noBuyer
        FROM #customers as c
        LEFT JOIN(
                -- All customers who have a transaction in the last 2 months
                SELECT DISTINCT CustNum
                FROM #orders
                -- to get the 01/01/2015 out of 03/2015
                WHERE Orderdate BETWEEN DATEADD(month,-2,
                                            CONVERT(date,N'01/'+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),m.allMonths)
                                            +N'/'+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),m.allYears)))
                                -- to get the 31/03/2015 out of the 03/2015                     
                                AND DATEADD(day,-1,
                                        DATEADD(month,+1,CONVERT(date,N'01/'+
                                            CONVERT(nvarchar(max),m.allMonths)+N'/'+
                                            CONVERT(nvarchar(max),m.allYears))))
                                -- NOTICE: the conversion to nvarchar is needed
                                -- After extracting the dateparts in the CTE, they are INT not DATE
                                -- A explicit conversion from INT to DATE isn't allowed
                                -- This way we cast it to NVARCHAR and convert it afterwards to DATE

            ) t
            ON c.CustNum = t.CustNum
        WHERE t.CustNum IS NULL
            -- optional: Count only users which were present in the counting month.
            AND t.CustRegdate >= CONVERT(date,N'01/'+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),m.allMonths)+N'/'+CONVERT(nvarchar(max),m.allYears))
    ) as monthyCustomers
ORDER BY m.allYears, m.allMonths

DROP TABLE #orders
DROP TABLE #customers
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for being insanely helpful, this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I know this may be a bit of a long shit, but can we count only the customers who were registered at the time we are counting for? For example, there is a field in `customers` table called `registerdate`. If a customer registered on Apr 1 2015, then we shouldn't count this customer for all the months prior to Apr 2015. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes this makes sense and should be an easy thing. I think it should be just an additional on clause at the join. I can provide it later as I'm on my way home. :-)

Comment: Hi, didn't make it yesterday evening. I've added an `AND`-clause to the `OUTER APPLY` `WHERE`-clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the customers that have not placed orders you are going to need a customer table and use an outer join to the orders table. This should be a starting point until you make your requirements clearer...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3aeb9/12

```
select c.CustNum ,odata.omonth from 
Customer c
left outer join
(select o.CustNum,
 REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), o.OrderDate, 106), 8), ' ', '-') 
  as OMONTH
from Orders o
where o.OrderDate between '2015-05-01' and '2015-06-30'
) odata
on c.CustNum = odata.CustNum
where odata.omonth is null;
```

Note that your code will need to be more complicated than this... but it should give you an idea of how to start.

Comment: sorry for not putting up a clearer question, I have edited it now. Yes, I do have a `customer` table having customer information.

Answer (score 0):

```
   select TOP 2 year(orderdate), month (orderdate),  
   (select count (*) FROM CUTOMER)  - count (distinct custnum) 
    from orders 
   group by  year (orderdate),month (orderdate)
   order by year (ORDERDATE),MONTH (ORDERDATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
select  
  b.mobile_number, max(b.bill_number), max(b.created_on), c.name
from 
  MasterBill as b, MasterCustomer as c
WHERE 
  b.created_on < NOW() - INTERVAL 60 DAY 
  and b.mobile_number = c.mobile_number
group by 
  mobile_number;
```